# separated mysql statement query in php

Tags: php, mysql

So,
I can run the following statements from within mysql itself successfully.

```
SET @fname = 'point1';
SELECT * FROM country WHERE name=@fname;`
```

But when I try to pass the query through php like this and run it, I get an error on the second line

```
$query = "SET @fname = 'point1';";

$query  .=  "SELECT * FROM country WHERE name=@fname;";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not certain why it fails, but rather than writing it with MySQL variables, why not use PHP variables?

In other words,

```
$fname = 'point1';
$query = "select * from country where name = '$fname'";
```

And the normal warning against SQL injection applies, of course.

Comment: Could also use a prepared statement which would kill SQL injection altogether

Comment: Yeah, I agree.  I was trying to keep it simple.

Answer (score 2):

You can't run multiple statements through PHP's mysql libraries without using a special function.  But your SQL variable should persist through your connection, so instead of concatenating the strings and running once, execute each statement separately.

Comment: I didn't know they would persist.  In Oracle they die (AFAIK)

Comment: Special function meaning code that parses and separates your statements and runs the queries separately for you.

Comment: There is the mysqli_multi_query function, but I don't recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

PHP's mysql drivers do not allow multiple queries to be executed from a single query function call as a security measure. It's a partial mitigation against the worst of SQL injection attacks, making the classic [XKCD Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) attack ineffective.

That's not to say that it makes injection attacks impossible - it just makes the multi-query version of the attacks impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Also have a look at [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php#91669) and [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php#89281) comments at `mysql_query()` doc page.